# php code dont update from form

Tags: php, pdo

im making a update profile script.. I have x fields and im testing with a var_dump($_POST) on the top of the form. The var_dump shows everything is right, but in the update code it does update anything.

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
                $firstname      = $_POST['firstname'];
                $lastname       = $_POST['lastname'];
                $phone          = $_POST['phone'];
                $profileText    = $_POST['profileText'];
                $website        = $_POST['website'];
                $username       = $_SESSION['username'];

                $stmt = $this->_db->execute("UPDATE `members` SET `firstname` = '$firstname', `lastname` = '$lastname', `phone` = '$phone', `profileText` = '$profileText', `website` = '$website' WHERE `username` = '$username'");

}
```

And it doesn't give me any errors, so cant give you an error message..

Html form:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Fornavn</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $userInfo->firstname; ?>" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Efternavn</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $userInfo->lastname; ?>" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Mobil Nummer</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $userInfo->phone; ?>" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Job Titel</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $userInfo->work; ?>" name="work" id="work" class="form-control" disabled/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Profil Tekst</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="profileText" id="profileText" value="<?php echo $userInfo->profileText; ?>"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Hjemmeside URL</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $userInfo->website; ?>" name="website" id="website" class="form-control"/>
</div>
<div class="margiv-top-10">
<input type="submit" class="btn green" value="Gem" >
<a href="profile.html" class="btn default">Annuller </a>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You don't get errors because you don't check for them. You're also wide open to SQL injections.

Comment: Im checking with setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: Ooh, this makes me want to sign up with `firstname=';DROP TABLE members;--`

Comment: Just using `setAttribute` sometimes isn't enough. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Make sure `session_start();` is also loaded. Your `WHERE` clause relies on it.

Comment: I do also have error_reporting..

Comment: All form elements are indeed named (including submit button), no typos etc.? DB table is correct, DB selection, columns, check everything from A to triple ZZZ.

Comment: Consult Tibor's answer below. You need to bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a function which is not available in the PDO class. It is however available in the PDOStatement class, which comes to play when you use `prepare`. Also, if you use PDO, then please, for the sake of a safer internet, use prepared statements. Example:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstname      = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname       = $_POST['lastname'];
    $phone          = $_POST['phone'];
    $profileText    = $_POST['profileText'];
    $website        = $_POST['website'];
    $username       = $_SESSION['username'];

    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE `members` SET `firstname` = :firstname, `lastname` = :lastname, `phone` = :phone, `profileText` = :profileText, `website` = :website WHERE `username` = :username");

    $stmt->bindParam(":firstname", $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":lastname", $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":phone", $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":profileText", $profileText, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":website", $website, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

If I were you I'd even add a server side check if all of those fields have been filled as well. A quick and dirty way of doing it is the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstname      = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : null;
    $lastname       = isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : null;
    $phone          = isset($_POST['phone'] ? $_POST['phone'] : null;
    $profileText    = isset($_POST['profileText'] ? $_POST['profileText'] : null;
    $website        = isset($_POST['website']) ? $_POST['website'] : null;
    $username       = isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : null;

    if (!in_array(null, array($firstname, $lastname, $phone, $profileText, $website, $username))) {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE `members` SET `firstname` = :firstname, `lastname` = :lastname, `phone` = :phone, `profileText` = :profileText, `website` = :website WHERE `username` = :username");

        $stmt->bindParam(":firstname", $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":lastname", $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":phone", $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":profileText", $profileText, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":website", $website, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->execute();
    } else {
        // tell them to fill in all of their details
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't update the users profile. The var dump looks like this: `array(5) { ["firstname"]=> string(4) "test" ["lastname"]=> string(4) "test" ["phone"]=> string(8) "00000000" ["profileText"]=> string(4) "test" ["website"]=> string(4) "test" }`

Comment: What about your username? What happens, if you simply just echo the username? If you don't get anything, then you should put `session_start();` before setting your `$username` variable.

Comment: Okay, then I think I cannot help you any more from the information you've specified. I don't know how does your connection look like, nor your HTML form.

Comment: Is PHP actually going into that `if(`? Do you have a `name` tag on your Submit button?

Comment: Ah, I've just checked your updated post. You don't have a `name` tag for your `submit` button. Please add `name="submit"` to it, and it should work. It wasn't showing an error, as it wasn't even going into that `if` condition.